# Vertically justify frame before page break using mdframed

Tags: vertical-alignment, mdframed

When `mdframed` breaks a page, it appears that there is no vertical justification on the page before the page break. Compiling the code sample below for example, it can be seen that there is more vertical space left between the frame and the page number on page 2 than on page 1.

Is there a setting that can vertically justify the content in the frame, such that the page before the break is filled?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{lightgrey}{RGB}{229,229,229}

\mdfsetup{
 backgroundcolor=lightgrey,
 linewidth=0pt,
 skipabove=12pt,
 skipbelow=12pt,
 leftmargin=0pt,
 rightmargin=0pt,
 innertopmargin=10pt,
 innerbottommargin=10pt,
 innerleftmargin=10pt,
 innerrightmargin=10pt,
 splittopskip=2\topsep
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}

\lipsum
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
    c^2 = a^2 + b^2
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
    r^2 = x^2 + y^2
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3]

\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use tcolorbox instead of mdframed - it handles breaking *much* better.

Comment: This is good advice.

Answer (score 0):

With `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{lightgrey}{RGB}{229,229,229}

\tcbset{
    breakable,
    sharp corners,
    colback=lightgrey,
    colframe=lightgrey,
    after skip=12pt,
    before skip=12pt,
    left=10pt,
    right=10pt,
    top=8pt,
    bottom=8pt,
    boxsep=0pt
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}

\lipsum
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
    c^2 = a^2 + b^2
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
    r^2 = x^2 + y^2
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3]

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, with the displayed formula, a little difference still exists.